# ADF af:inputColor preselection and getting new selection

Tags: jsf, richfaces, oracle-adf

I'm using JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0

I have a table with F_ID, F_DESC and F_COLOR fields.

They are mapped in Entity and VO with FId, FDesc and FColor.

Values are:

*1 - Desc1 - #FF0000*

*2 - Desc2 - #AA3322*

So, in mi view, in the edition mode, I want to edit FColor value as an af:inputColor component.

So, how can I set (or preselect) the current color in table?

If this color changes, how can I get the new color?

Thank you. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full answer for getting and setting color is here. The steps are:

1. [Create a transient attribute of type java.awt.Color](https://community.oracle.com/message/10808132#10808132)
2. Custom getter/setter in ViewRowImpl to map string value to java.awt.Color value
3. Include an  mapped to java.awt.Color

For steps two and three, see: https://community.oracle.com/message/2565526#2565526

This has worked for me for getting and setting value in database.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use the af:convertColor and give it a pattern, that way your string will be presented and submitted back.
For reference about af:convertColor check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_convertColor.html) and [here](http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_convertColor.html)

Comment: thank you for your answer. The color string is in the right format, but I don't know why, put #{binding.FColor.inputValue} in af:inputColor does not work. Finally, I setted manually and works.

Comment: @yaki_nuka Did you use af:convertColor inside of your inputColor?

Comment: no, finally I use an af:inputColor with the code in the other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20070183/543320

Comment: I can understand it's working and I'm glad it does, but this is a hack and is not the proper way to work with af:inputColor.